# Inserting into Mysql master table of very large varchar fields

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have my master table of sources:

```
CREATE TABLE masterSources (
pk int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(500)
);

INSERT INTO masterSources (name) VALUES 
('derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:iphone:1213084:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:f8df280c:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps'),
('derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:iphone:1213084:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:f8df280c:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:f8df280c:session_activity_segment'),
('derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:iphone:1213084:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:f8df280c:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_activities');
```

Then, I receive thousands and thousands of sources that I can bulk into this table:

```
CREATE TABLE receivedSources (
name VARCHAR(500)
);

INSERT INTO receivedSources (name) VALUES 
('derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:iphone:1213084:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:f8df280c:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:f8df280c:top_level'), #repeated
('derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:gew8df280c:top_level'), #new
('derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:ged8df280c:low_level'), #new
('derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps'),
('derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps'), #repeated
('derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:iphone:1213084:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:f8df280c:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:f8df280c:session_activity_segment'),
('derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:iphone:1213084:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:iphone:1213084:top_level'), #repeated
('derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.ios.fit:appleinc.:watch:f8df280c:top_level'),
('derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:fromx2_activities'), #new
('derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_activities');
```

What I want is to add the "new" sources into my `masterSources` table and finally generate a new table associating each source from `receivedSources` with its corresponding pk.

I can do it with a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure()
BEGIN
    DECLARE newName VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;                     


    # receivedSources MINUS masterSources 
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR  SELECT n.name 
                            FROM receivedSources n LEFT JOIN masterSources m ON (n.name=m.name)
                            WHERE m.pk IS NULL;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = TRUE;
    
    OPEN cur;

    loop1: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO newName;
   
        IF done THEN 
            LEAVE loop1;            
        END IF; 
    
        # Inserting new Sources in master
        INSERT INTO masterSources (name) VALUES (newName);     

    END LOOP loop1;
    CLOSE cur;
   
    # Getting my desired table
    CREATE TABLE newReceivedSources AS
    SELECT m.pk,m.name FROM receivedSources n INNER JOIN masterSources m ON (n.name=m.name);

END

call my_procedure()

select * from newReceivedSources
```

[image]

My question: Is there a faster/smarter way to do it, considering how expensive is the join by `varchar` fields?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add a unique key on `masterSources (name)`?  Then you could simply do an `INSERT IGNORE` from `receivedSources` into `masterSources`, followed by a simple join to get the desired output.  Adding a key on `receivedSources (name)` would also improve performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a unique key on `masterSources`

```
ALTER TABLE masterSources ADD UNIQUE KEY (name)
```

(Optional) to increase performance, also add a (non-unique) key on `receivedSources`

```
ALTER TABLE receivedSources ADD KEY (name)
```

Then insert any new unique values into masterSources

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO masterSources (name) SELECT name FROM receivedSources
```

Then retrieve your desired dataset

```
SELECT masterSources.pk, masterSources.name
FROM receivedSources
INNER JOIN masterSources ON receivedSources.name = masterSources.name
```